# SVG animateMotion duration not working properly

Tags: svg

I want the dark blue dots to run on same speed and the duration is same still one dot is a little late, also I want that after the logo's circle all the dots will combine as one big dot and then move to the laptop icon.

Here it what I tried..
Kindly help

Here is the snippet

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 970 570" style="enable-background:new 0 0 970 570;" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:none;stroke:#303D4F;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st1{fill:#21A8E0;}
 .st2{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st3{font-family:'Lato-Light';}
 .st4{font-size:16px;}
 .st5{fill:#303D4F;stroke:#303D4F;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st6{fill:#6EC5E0;}
 .st7{fill:#DDE9F1;}
 .st8{fill:none;stroke:#303D4F;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st9{fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:#303D4F;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st10{fill:#FAFBFC;stroke:#303D4F;stroke-width:2;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
 .st11{fill:#303D4F;}
 path {
     stroke-dasharray: 1093.92, 1093.92;
     stroke-dashoffset: 0;
     transition-timing-function: linear;
     transition-duration: 2.5s;
     transition-delay: 0.5s;
     animation-duration: 2.5s;
 }
</style>
</defs>
<g>
 <g>
  <path class="st0" d="M467.9,306.3H150.1c-11.9,0-21.6,9.7-21.6,21.6v74.5" id="path-to-trace-6"/>
  <path class="st0" d="M467.9,263.6H185.8c-11.9,0-21.6-9.7-21.6-21.6V101.8" id="path-to-trace-1"/>
  <path class="st0" d="M467.9,284.7H120.3c-11.9,0-21.6-9.7-21.6-21.6V222" id="path-to-trace-2"/>
  <path class="st0" d="M280.7,165.9v70.3c0,4,3.2,7.2,7.2,7.2h180.1l35.9,51.8" id="path-to-trace-3"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0,0h204.6" id="last-path"></path>
  <line fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="440.3" y1="295.2" x2="819" y2="295.2"></line>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M139.5,201.8c0,11-9,20-20,20H78c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h41.6c11,0,20,9,20,20V201.8z"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 80.6445 205.3301)" class="st2 st3 st4">Trade</text>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M213.1,425.8c0,11-9,20-20,20h-92.1c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h92.1c11,0,20,9,20,20V425.8z"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 110.1387 429.3643)" class="st2 st3 st4">Derivatives</text>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M359.7,146.8c0,11-9,20-20,20H218c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h121.7c11,0,20,9,20,20V146.8z"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 220.1895 150.3301)" class="st2 st3 st4">Macro-economics</text>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M250.6,83c0,11-9,20-20,20H97.8c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h132.9c11,0,20,9,20,20V83z"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 101.3477 86.4922)" class="st2 st3 st4">Supply v/s demand</text>
  <path class="st0" d="M467.9,327.4H248.2c-11.9,0-21.6,9.7-21.6,21.6v119.2" id="path-to-trace-4"/>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M307.5,491.5c0,11-9,20-20,20H165.7c-11,0-20-9-20-20V487c0-11,9-20,20-20h121.7c11,0,20,9,20,20V491.5z"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 167.916 495.042)" class="st2 st3 st4">Financial markets</text>
  <g>
   <path class="st1" d="M367.4,408.7c0,11-9,20-20,20h-84.8c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h84.8c11,0,20,9,20,20V408.7z"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 267.4238 412.1934)" class="st2 st3 st4">Geo politics</text>
  <path class="st0" d="M467.9,347.7H311c-4,0-7.2,3.2-7.2,7.2v29.4" id="path-to-trace-5"/>
  <circle fill="#313c50" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
    <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite"  keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
         <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path-to-trace-1"></mpath>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
   <circle fill="#313c50" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
     <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
         <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path-to-trace-2"></mpath>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
   <circle fill="#313c50" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
     <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
         <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path-to-trace-3"></mpath>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
   <circle fill="#313c50" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
    <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
         <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path-to-trace-6"></mpath>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
   <circle fill="#313c50" cx=" " cy="" r="6.7">
    <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
         <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path-to-trace-4"></mpath>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
   <circle fill="#313c50" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
    <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto" id="smallCircle">
         <mpath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#path-to-trace-5"></mpath>
       </animateMotion>
   </circle>
   <circle class="st5" cx="" cy="" r="11.2">
    <animateMotion begin="smallCircle.end-0.5s" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" id="bigCircle">
            <mpath xlink:href="#last-path"></mpath>
          </animateMotion>
   </circle>
  <g>
   <circle class="st6" cx="503.9" cy="292" r="79.4"/>
   <g>
    <path class="st2" d="M478.4,276.5l-0.2,1.8c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.5-0.4,0.7l-18.1,24.8h15.2l-0.6,4.7h-23
     l0.2-1.8c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.4-0.7l18.2-24.9h-14.5l0.6-4.7H478.4z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M494,309.3c-0.7,0-1.2-0.2-1.4-0.5c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.7-0.4-1.2l0.2-3.4c-1.1,1.7-2.4,3-3.8,4
     c-1.4,1-2.9,1.5-4.4,1.5c-1,0-1.8-0.2-2.6-0.5c-0.8-0.4-1.5-0.9-2-1.6c-0.6-0.7-1-1.6-1.3-2.7c-0.3-1.1-0.5-2.4-0.5-3.9
     c0-1.3,0.1-2.6,0.4-3.9c0.3-1.3,0.7-2.5,1.2-3.6c0.5-1.1,1.1-2.2,1.8-3.1c0.7-1,1.5-1.8,2.3-2.5c0.8-0.7,1.7-1.2,2.7-1.6
     c1-0.4,2-0.6,3-0.6c1,0,2,0.2,2.8,0.6c0.8,0.4,1.6,0.9,2.2,1.5l1.5-12.2h5.5l-4.1,33.7H494z M486.3,305.2c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.9-0.6
     c0.6-0.4,1.2-1,1.8-1.7c0.6-0.7,1.1-1.6,1.6-2.6c0.5-1,0.9-2.1,1.3-3.2l0.7-5.6c-0.5-0.6-1.1-1-1.8-1.2
     c-0.7-0.2-1.3-0.3-1.9-0.3c-1,0-1.9,0.3-2.7,0.9c-0.8,0.6-1.5,1.4-2.1,2.4c-0.6,1-1,2.1-1.3,3.4c-0.3,1.2-0.5,2.5-0.5,3.8
     c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,0.8,3.6C484.6,304.8,485.4,305.2,486.3,305.2z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M520.6,309.3h-2.9c-0.7,0-1.2-0.2-1.4-0.5c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.7-0.4-1.2l0.2-3.2c-1,1.6-2.2,2.9-3.5,3.8
     c-1.3,0.9-2.7,1.4-4.2,1.4c-0.9,0-1.7-0.2-2.5-0.5c-0.8-0.3-1.4-0.9-2-1.6c-0.6-0.7-1-1.5-1.3-2.6c-0.3-1-0.5-2.3-0.5-3.6
     c0-1.4,0.2-2.7,0.5-4.1c0.3-1.3,0.8-2.5,1.5-3.7c0.6-1.2,1.4-2.2,2.3-3.2c0.9-1,1.9-1.8,3-2.5c1.1-0.7,2.3-1.2,3.6-1.6
     c1.3-0.4,2.7-0.6,4.1-0.6c1,0,2.1,0.1,3.1,0.2c1,0.2,2.1,0.4,3.1,0.8L520.6,309.3z M510.5,305.1c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.8-0.6
     c0.6-0.4,1.2-1,1.7-1.8c0.5-0.8,1-1.6,1.5-2.6c0.5-1,0.8-2.1,1.2-3.3l0.9-7c-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.1-0.1c-1.3,0-2.4,0.3-3.5,0.9
     c-1.1,0.6-2,1.3-2.8,2.3c-0.8,1-1.4,2.1-1.8,3.4c-0.4,1.3-0.7,2.7-0.7,4.1c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,0.8,3.6
     C508.9,304.7,509.6,305.1,510.5,305.1z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M526.1,309.3l4.1-33.7h5.5l-4.1,33.7H526.1z"/>
    <path class="st2" d="M544.4,315.7c-0.4,0.8-1,1.2-1.8,1.2h-4.1l5.2-9.4l-5.9-21.5h4.7c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,0.9,0.3
     c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7l2.9,12.1c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.2,1.2c0.1,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.1,1.2c0.2-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.5-1.2
     c0.2-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.5-1.2l5.7-12.1c0.2-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.7-0.7c0.3-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3h4.5L544.4,315.7z"/>
     
   </g>
  </g>
  <g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <path class="st7" d="M896.5,346.9c0,2.6-2.1,4.8-4.7,4.8H713.2c-2.6,0-4.7-2.1-4.7-4.8V224.8c0-2.6,2.1-4.7,4.7-4.7h178.5
      c2.6,0,4.7,2.1,4.7,4.7V346.9z"/>
     <path class="st8" d="M896.5,346.9c0,2.6-2.1,4.8-4.7,4.8H713.2c-2.6,0-4.7-2.1-4.7-4.8V224.8c0-2.6,2.1-4.7,4.7-4.7h178.5
      c2.6,0,4.7,2.1,4.7,4.7V346.9z"/>
    </g>
    <rect x="719.5" y="231.1" class="st9" width="166" height="109.5"/>
    <path class="st10" d="M907.6,360.2c-46.3,0-157.1,0-210.3,0c-2.4,0-4.4-8.5-4.4-8.5H912C912,351.7,910,360.2,907.6,360.2z"/>
    <polygon class="st10" points="829.2,355.3 775.7,355.3 774.6,351.7 830.3,351.7     "/>
   </g>
   <g>
    <g>
     <path class="st11" d="M759.4,320.2c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-64.6c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v64.6
      C760.2,319.8,759.8,320.2,759.4,320.2z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <path class="st11" d="M849.7,320.2h-90.3c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h90.3c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9
      C850.5,319.8,850.1,320.2,849.7,320.2z"/>
    </g>
    <g>
     <path class="st11" d="M775.9,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-44c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v44
      C776.8,319.8,776.4,320.2,775.9,320.2z M767.4,318.5h7.6v-42.2h-7.6V318.5z"/>
    </g>
    <path class="st11" d="M791.8,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-62.4c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v62.4
     C792.7,319.8,792.3,320.2,791.8,320.2z M783.3,318.5h7.6v-60.7h-7.6V318.5z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M807.7,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9V267c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v52.4
     C808.6,319.8,808.2,320.2,807.7,320.2z M799.2,318.5h7.6v-50.6h-7.6V318.5z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M823.6,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-36.8c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v36.8
     C824.5,319.8,824.1,320.2,823.6,320.2z M815.1,318.5h7.6v-35h-7.6V318.5z"/>
    <path class="st11" d="M840.1,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-46.4c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v46.4
     C841,319.8,840.6,320.2,840.1,320.2z M831.6,318.5h7.6v-44.6h-7.6V318.5z"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

You see a big circle in dark blue color at corner, something like that will move when all small dots finish there animation, that big circle will move on the line which is between the logo circle and laptop icon. I hope you are understand what I am trying to say.

Update :
This is the latest snippet I tried, but I am not sure which part I am not doing correctly to make that dark blue circle move.

Comment: My apologies. The answer I posted (tacking on `h204.6` to `path-to-trace-3`'s `d` attribute), didn't address your second problem, because it doesn't seem to be a problem in Firefox, where I was initially working. I'll delete that answer, lest others think this is fully solved.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, @MaxStarkenburg was completely right, the upper path doesn't have the same length as others, hence it won't take the same time for his dot to make the whole journey.

For the second part, I would start a new animation after the first one has finished using the `animationID.end` [begin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/begin) value.

Here is how it could looks like :

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 970 570" enable-background="new 0 0 970 570" xml:space="preserve">
  <defs>
    <style>
      path {
        stroke-dasharray: 1093.92, 1093.92;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        transition-timing-function: linear;
        transition-duration: 2.5s;
        transition-delay: 0.5s;
        animation-duration: 2.5s;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <g>

      <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M164.2,101.8V242c0,11.9,9.7,21.6,21.6,21.6h282.1l35.9,31.6" id="path-to-trace-1"></path>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M98.7,212v51.1c0,11.9,9.7,21.6,21.6,21.6h347.6l35.9,10.5" id="path-to-trace-2"></path>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M280.7,165.9v70.3c0,4,3.2,7.2,7.2,7.2h180.1l35.9,51.8" id="path-to-trace-3"></path>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M303.8,384.2v-29.4c0-4,3.2-7.2,7.2-7.2h156.9l35.9-52.4" id="path-to-trace-5"></path>
      <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M128.5,402.4V327c0-10.9,9.7-20.6,21.6-20.6h317.8l35.9-11.1" id="path-to-trace-6"></path>
      <path fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M0,0h204.6" id="last-path"></path>

      <line fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="440.3" y1="295.2" x2="819" y2="295.2"></line>

      <circle fill="#21A8E0" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
        <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
          <mpath xlink:href="#path-to-trace-1"></mpath>
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="#21A8E0" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
        <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
          <mpath xlink:href="#path-to-trace-2"></mpath>
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="#21A8E0" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
        <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
          <mpath xlink:href="#path-to-trace-3"></mpath>
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="#21A8E0" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
        <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto" id="smallCircle">
          <mpath xlink:href="#path-to-trace-5"></mpath>
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <circle fill="#21A8E0" cx="" cy="" r="6.7">
        <animateMotion begin="0s;bigCircle.end" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" rotate="auto">
          <mpath xlink:href="#path-to-trace-6"></mpath>
        </animateMotion>
      </circle>
      <g>
        <circle fill="#6EC5E0" cx="503.9" cy="292" r="79.4"></circle>
        <g>
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M478.4,276.5l-0.2,1.8c0,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.5-0.4,0.7l-18.1,24.8h15.2l-0.6,4.7h-23
     l0.2-1.8c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2-0.7c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.5,0.4-0.7l18.2-24.9h-14.5l0.6-4.7H478.4z"></path>
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M494,309.3c-0.7,0-1.2-0.2-1.4-0.5c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.7-0.4-1.2l0.2-3.4c-1.1,1.7-2.4,3-3.8,4
     c-1.4,1-2.9,1.5-4.4,1.5c-1,0-1.8-0.2-2.6-0.5c-0.8-0.4-1.5-0.9-2-1.6c-0.6-0.7-1-1.6-1.3-2.7c-0.3-1.1-0.5-2.4-0.5-3.9
     c0-1.3,0.1-2.6,0.4-3.9c0.3-1.3,0.7-2.5,1.2-3.6c0.5-1.1,1.1-2.2,1.8-3.1c0.7-1,1.5-1.8,2.3-2.5c0.8-0.7,1.7-1.2,2.7-1.6
     c1-0.4,2-0.6,3-0.6c1,0,2,0.2,2.8,0.6c0.8,0.4,1.6,0.9,2.2,1.5l1.5-12.2h5.5l-4.1,33.7H494z M486.3,305.2c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.9-0.6
     c0.6-0.4,1.2-1,1.8-1.7c0.6-0.7,1.1-1.6,1.6-2.6c0.5-1,0.9-2.1,1.3-3.2l0.7-5.6c-0.5-0.6-1.1-1-1.8-1.2
     c-0.7-0.2-1.3-0.3-1.9-0.3c-1,0-1.9,0.3-2.7,0.9c-0.8,0.6-1.5,1.4-2.1,2.4c-0.6,1-1,2.1-1.3,3.4c-0.3,1.2-0.5,2.5-0.5,3.8
     c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,0.8,3.6C484.6,304.8,485.4,305.2,486.3,305.2z"></path>
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M520.6,309.3h-2.9c-0.7,0-1.2-0.2-1.4-0.5c-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.7-0.4-1.2l0.2-3.2c-1,1.6-2.2,2.9-3.5,3.8
     c-1.3,0.9-2.7,1.4-4.2,1.4c-0.9,0-1.7-0.2-2.5-0.5c-0.8-0.3-1.4-0.9-2-1.6c-0.6-0.7-1-1.5-1.3-2.6c-0.3-1-0.5-2.3-0.5-3.6
     c0-1.4,0.2-2.7,0.5-4.1c0.3-1.3,0.8-2.5,1.5-3.7c0.6-1.2,1.4-2.2,2.3-3.2c0.9-1,1.9-1.8,3-2.5c1.1-0.7,2.3-1.2,3.6-1.6
     c1.3-0.4,2.7-0.6,4.1-0.6c1,0,2.1,0.1,3.1,0.2c1,0.2,2.1,0.4,3.1,0.8L520.6,309.3z M510.5,305.1c0.6,0,1.2-0.2,1.8-0.6
     c0.6-0.4,1.2-1,1.7-1.8c0.5-0.8,1-1.6,1.5-2.6c0.5-1,0.8-2.1,1.2-3.3l0.9-7c-0.4,0-0.8-0.1-1.1-0.1c-1.3,0-2.4,0.3-3.5,0.9
     c-1.1,0.6-2,1.3-2.8,2.3c-0.8,1-1.4,2.1-1.8,3.4c-0.4,1.3-0.7,2.7-0.7,4.1c0,1.6,0.3,2.8,0.8,3.6
     C508.9,304.7,509.6,305.1,510.5,305.1z"></path>
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M526.1,309.3l4.1-33.7h5.5l-4.1,33.7H526.1z"></path>
          <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M544.4,315.7c-0.4,0.8-1,1.2-1.8,1.2h-4.1l5.2-9.4l-5.9-21.5h4.7c0.4,0,0.7,0.1,0.9,0.3
     c0.2,0.2,0.3,0.5,0.4,0.7l2.9,12.1c0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.2,1.2c0.1,0.4,0.1,0.8,0.1,1.2c0.2-0.4,0.3-0.8,0.5-1.2
     c0.2-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.5-1.2l5.7-12.1c0.2-0.3,0.4-0.5,0.7-0.7c0.3-0.2,0.6-0.3,0.9-0.3h4.5L544.4,315.7z"></path>
        </g>
        <animateMotion begin="smallCircle.end-0.5s" dur="4s" calcMode="linear" id="bigCircle">
          <mpath xlink:href="#last-path"></mpath>
        </animateMotion>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g>
      <g>
        <path fill="#21A8E0" d="M139.5,201.8c0,11-9,20-20,20H78c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h41.6c11,0,20,9,20,20V201.8z"></path>
      </g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 80.6445 205.3301)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Lato-Light'" font-size="16px">Trade</text>
      <g>
        <path fill="#21A8E0" d="M213.1,425.8c0,11-9,20-20,20h-92.1c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h92.1c11,0,20,9,20,20V425.8z"></path>
      </g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 110.1387 429.3643)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Lato-Light'" font-size="16px">Derivatives</text>
      <g>
        <path fill="#21A8E0" d="M359.7,146.8c0,11-9,20-20,20H218c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h121.7c11,0,20,9,20,20V146.8z"></path>
      </g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 220.1895 150.3301)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Lato-Light'" font-size="16px">Macro-economics</text>
      <g>
        <path fill="#21A8E0" d="M250.6,83c0,11-9,20-20,20H97.8c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h132.9c11,0,20,9,20,20V83z"></path>
      </g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 101.3477 86.4922)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Lato-Light'" font-size="16px">Supply v/s demand</text>
      <g>
        <path fill="#21A8E0" d="M307.5,491.5c0,11-9,20-20,20H165.7c-11,0-20-9-20-20V487c0-11,9-20,20-20h121.7c11,0,20,9,20,20V491.5z"></path>
      </g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 167.916 495.042)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Lato-Light'" font-size="16px">Financial markets</text>
      <g>
        <path fill="#21A8E0" d="M367.4,408.7c0,11-9,20-20,20h-84.8c-11,0-20-9-20-20v-4.5c0-11,9-20,20-20h84.8c11,0,20,9,20,20V408.7z"></path>
      </g>
      <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 267.4238 412.1934)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'Lato-Light'" font-size="16px">Geo politics</text>
      <g>
        <g>
          <g>
            <path fill="#DDE9F1" d="M896.5,346.9c0,2.6-2.1,4.8-4.7,4.8H713.2c-2.6,0-4.7-2.1-4.7-4.8V224.8c0-2.6,2.1-4.7,4.7-4.7h178.5
      c2.6,0,4.7,2.1,4.7,4.7V346.9z"></path>

            <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
      M896.5,346.9c0,2.6-2.1,4.8-4.7,4.8H713.2c-2.6,0-4.7-2.1-4.7-4.8V224.8c0-2.6,2.1-4.7,4.7-4.7h178.5c2.6,0,4.7,2.1,4.7,4.7
      V346.9z"></path>
          </g>

          <rect x="719.5" y="231.1" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="166" height="109.5"></rect>

          <path fill="#FAFBFC" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
     M907.6,360.2c-46.3,0-157.1,0-210.3,0c-2.4,0-4.4-8.5-4.4-8.5H912C912,351.7,910,360.2,907.6,360.2z"></path>

          <polygon fill="#FAFBFC" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="
     829.2,355.3 775.7,355.3 774.6,351.7 830.3,351.7     "></polygon>
        </g>
        <g>
          <g>
            <path fill="#303D4F" d="M759.4,320.2c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-64.6c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v64.6
      C760.2,319.8,759.8,320.2,759.4,320.2z"></path>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path fill="#303D4F" d="M849.7,320.2h-90.3c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h90.3c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9
      C850.5,319.8,850.1,320.2,849.7,320.2z"></path>
          </g>
          <g>
            <path fill="#303D4F" d="M775.9,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-44c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v44
      C776.8,319.8,776.4,320.2,775.9,320.2z M767.4,318.5h7.6v-42.2h-7.6V318.5z"></path>
          </g>
          <path fill="#303D4F" d="M791.8,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-62.4c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v62.4
     C792.7,319.8,792.3,320.2,791.8,320.2z M783.3,318.5h7.6v-60.7h-7.6V318.5z"></path>
          <path fill="#303D4F" d="M807.7,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9V267c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v52.4
     C808.6,319.8,808.2,320.2,807.7,320.2z M799.2,318.5h7.6v-50.6h-7.6V318.5z"></path>
          <path fill="#303D4F" d="M823.6,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-36.8c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v36.8
     C824.5,319.8,824.1,320.2,823.6,320.2z M815.1,318.5h7.6v-35h-7.6V318.5z"></path>
          <path fill="#303D4F" d="M840.1,320.2h-9.4c-0.5,0-0.9-0.4-0.9-0.9v-46.4c0-0.5,0.4-0.9,0.9-0.9h9.4c0.5,0,0.9,0.4,0.9,0.9v46.4
     C841,319.8,840.6,320.2,840.1,320.2z M831.6,318.5h7.6v-44.6h-7.6V318.5z"></path>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#303D4F" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M708.5,295.2"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: wow.....my first problem is solved thanks to you, but I want not that logo circle to move, I want to move the all the dots as one dot to the laptop after it pass to the logo.. You got what I mean?
Ok, but as you suggested to add another animation I will try that, but how it will be possible to combine all small dots as one?

Comment: well just create a new circle

Comment: The second animation could just be one dot, moving from behind the big circle to the laptop (while the other dots just stay hiding behind the big circle), no? (What Kaiido said, a minute before I did :-))

Comment: Exactly this is what I am trying to say..  @MaxStarkenburg Also in the above snippet I have put that code, that circle doesn't work, because that line which is between the logo circle and laptop is not an <path> but line tag. And I am very new to SVG, So I tried how Kaiido demonstrated with the logo circle. but it didnot work for me, I don't know what step I left

Comment: @srijanair, in the snippet I gave you, I created a path`#last-path` usable by `<mpath>`. You just have to create a new circle, the size you want, position it behind your logo, and move the `<animateMotion ...` currently inside the logo's circle to your new circle. I'm not sure it will help you if I do this for you ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido, I did what you have done in the snippet also in the comment you said, took a circle, give that `<animateMotion ..` inside that circle and give the smallCircle to other dots and bigCircle to the new blue dot.. But it is not working.. Can you please give me idea what I am missing, I have added the latest snippet, can you please check it once. I will be grateful to you